# How to run JUnit 5 suite without @RunWith annotation

Tags: junit4, junit5, junit-runner

For suites I am using below [template](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner-test-suite):

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectPackages("com.services.configuration")
@ExcludeTags({IntegrationTags.JPA, IntegrationTags.REST})
public class UnitTestSuite {
}
```

`@RunWith` is a JUnit 4 dependency, which comes from

```
 compile "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.0.2"
```

Is it possible to have JUnit 5 suites without the JUnit 4 dependency? So that I could remove JUnit 4 from my dependencies?

Can't it be replaced with a proper `@ExtendsWith` extension? I need this only for suites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JUnitPlatform` runner is a means to execute tests written for JUnit Platform test engines, e.g. JUnit Jupiter tests, using JUnit 4. It is only an interim solution for tools that don't support the new JUnit Platform.

There's an open issue for the JUnit Platform to add support for declarative suites: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/744

For the time being, you can keep using JUnit 4 to run suites or define a custom Gradle task:

```
task unitTestSuite(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        excludeTags "JPA", "REST"
    }
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching "com.services.configuration.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.So now we need to wait. Because this dependency is for back-compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

I gave a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68898733/2330808

You can now run Suites purely with jUnit 5 engines:

```
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite

@Suite
@SelectPackages("com.services.configuration")
@ExcludeTags({IntegrationTags.JPA, IntegrationTags.REST})
public class UnitTestSuite {
}
```

You'll have to import the `junit-platform-suite-engine`:

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-suite-engine

eg `compile "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-engine:1.8.0-RC1"`

There's some docs here:

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#launcher-api-engines-custom
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/api/org.junit.platform.suite.engine/org/junit/platform/suite/engine/package-summary.html

Here's an official example:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/main/documentation/src/test/java/example/SuiteDemo.java