# Junit5 test suite with Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit5

Based on answer in [this link](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1334), created a test suite with Test classes

```
@RunWith(Suite::class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(
    DTOtoEntityMapperTest::class,
    PostDataSourceCoroutinesTest::class,
    PostDataSourceRxJava3Test::class
)
class JUnit5TestSuite
```

Returns error

```
org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'com.x.DTOtoEntityMapperTest':
  1. No runnable methods
```

But every test class added has test methods  and runs individually for instance

```
class DTOtoEntityMapperTest {

    private val postDTOList by lazy {
        convertFromJsonToObjectList<PostDTO>(getResourceAsText(RESPONSE_JSON_PATH))!!
    }

    private val postEntityList by lazy {
        convertFromJsonToObjectList<PostEntity>(getResourceAsText(RESPONSE_JSON_PATH))!!
    }

    @Test
    fun `given PostDTO is input, should return PostEntity`() {

        val mapper = DTOtoEntityMapper()

        // GIVEN
        val expected = postEntityList

        // WHEN
        val actual = mapper.map(postDTOList)

        // THEN
        Truth.assertThat(actual).containsExactlyElementsIn(expected)
    }
}
```

Comment: is your test annotation a junit 5 @Test annotation, is it of type org.junit.jupiter.api.Test?

Comment: @DanielJacob All tests are JUnit5 tests, it's org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

Comment: RunWith and Suite are JUnit 4 mechanisms that do not work with JUnit 5. Nowhere in the answer you’ve linked is your approach being suggested.

Comment: @johanneslink how can i run JUnit5 tests using a test suite? Yeah, i checked it the answer again, my mistake i thought **It cannot be used when running on the JUnit Platform. You should be able to use the Suite runner, though.** was refering to running with JUnit5 test. Can you provide an answer how to run tests with Junit5 test suite in Kotlin?

Comment: @Thracian Hand-crafted test suites are not a supported concept in JUnit 5. You can get around that by using RunWith(JUnitPlatform) but then you are using JUnit 4 to run JUnit 5. This construct was created as a workaround for the days when build tools and IDEs did not support JUnit 5. What is it you want to achieve with the suite?

Comment: @johanneslink i want to run all of the tests located in a module using a single file. I have over 15 test classes and more about 100 tests, including nested ones. What do you mean by **but then you are using JUnit 4 to run JUnit 5**, i can still use test suites with `RunWith(JUnitPlatform)`? I tried adding that to class i defined as test suite but AS couldn't find dependency. I assume from your comment if i add JUnit4 dependency i can run my JUnit5 tests with a test suite, right?

Comment: @Thracian JUnit 5 has the feature to run all tests of a module (or a package or a class) built in. You do not need suites for that. How you invoke that depends on IDE or build tool you are using.

Comment: @Thracian "i want to run all of the tests located in a module using a single file." Why exactly you need **one** file? If you want to run all test in intellij, just right click on the base package and run all unit tests. If you want  to run using build tool (gradle/maven) it does run **all** test automatically, don't need to specify files. The only real use-case for Suites is when you want to run tests in **parallel** groups with different contexts (e.g. spring `@DataJpaTest`, `@JsonTest`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now run Suites purely with jUnit 5 engines:

```
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite

@Suite
@SelectClasses(BasicMockKUnitTest::class, HierarchicalMockKUnitTest::class)
@SelectPackages("exercise")
class TestAllSelectPackage {
}
```

You'll have to import the `junit-platform-suite-engine`:

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-suite-engine

There's some docs here:

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#launcher-api-engines-custom
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/api/org.junit.platform.suite.engine/org/junit/platform/suite/engine/package-summary.html

Here's an official example:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/main/documentation/src/test/java/example/SuiteDemo.java

Answer (score 1):

For JUnit 5 I used JUnitPlatform and SelectClasses (or SelectPackages):

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
@SelectClasses(Some1Test::class, Some2Test::class)
class SuiteTest
```

Comment: I'm want to use test suite with junit5 and kotlin. could you please let to know which library can I import to able to use SelectClasses and SelectPackages annotation?

Comment: You need module "junit-platform-suite-api" of JUnit 5.

Answer (score 1):

After checking for a few days, I found correctly libs to use Junit 5 test suite with kotlin

In build.gradle, add 2 libs as below:

```
testImplementation ("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:1.7.0")
testImplementation ("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.2.0")
```

Then you can use test suite as below:

```
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages
import org.junit.runner.RunWith


@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
@SelectClasses(BasicMockKUnitTest::class, HierarchicalMockKUnitTest::class)
@SelectPackages("exercise")
class TestAllSelectPackage {
}
```